# Inno Setup - How to re-align the checkbox in the wpFinished page with image customized by ISSI script?

Tags: checkbox, inno-setup, issi

I am new to the Inno Setup concept but I still have created a installer with the help through Internet. I have been looking for a script to re-align the checkboxes (Direct X, DirectPlay) in the `wpFinished` page.

I have used the ISSI script to re-align the bitmap image (x180) which brings me this problem but I don't want to changes the image values and want to make changes by re-aligning the checkboxes.

[image]

In the above image where the red marking shows the error and the green shows where I want it. And lastly, I have never written a code before for Inno Setup so i have no idea how to start it.

I feel these few lines of script may be important:

```
[ISSI]
;SplashScreen
;; Name of the bitmap image:
#define ISSI_SplashScreen "C:\Users\Archangel_7\Downloads\Newfolder\AA_7.bmp"
;; Time in seconds:
#define ISSI_SplashScreen_T 1
;; Image Width:
#define ISSI_SplashScreen_X 488
;; Image Heigth:
#define ISSI_SplashScreen_Y 199
;; Include ISSI (required)
;WizardSmallBitmapImage [Default = [55x55]
#define ISSI_WizardSmallBitmapImage"C:\Users\Archangel_7\Downloads\ensemble.bmp"
#define ISSI_WizardSmallBitmapImage_x 70
;WizardBitmapImage [Front & Back] [Default = 164x314]
#define ISSI_WizardBitmapImage"C:\Users\Archangel_7\Downloads\AOE.bmp"
#define ISSI_WizardBitmapImage_x 180
;define ISSI_WizardBitmapImage_Align
#define ISSI_WizardBitmapImage2 "C:\Users\Archangel_7\Downloads\AOE.bmp"
#define ISSI_WizardBitmapImage2_x 180
;define ISSI_WizardBitmapImage2_Align
;[Background Image]
;define ISSI_Image "C:\Users\Archangel_7\Downloads\AA7.bmp"
#define ISSI_IncludePath "C:\ISSI"
#include ISSI_IncludePath+"\_issi.isi"

[Files]
Source: C:\Users\Archangel_7\Desktop\Age of Empires\Redistributab\Directx\Dplay50a.exe; DestDir: {app}\Redistributable\Directx
Source: C:\Users\Archangel_7\Desktop\Age of Empires\Redistributable\Directx\Dxsetup.exe; DestDir: {app}\Redistributable\Directx

[Run]
Filename: {app}\Redistributable\Directx\Dxsetup.exe; Description: Direct X; Flags: postinstall
Filename: {app}\Redistributable\Directx\Dplay50a.exe; Description: Direct Play v5.0a; Flags: postinstall
```

Comment: @MartinPrikryl ISSI script is up.

Comment: Microsoft would be proud of you for making an effort to stealing their game and making your own setup for it. You could at least preserve that image aspect ratio. It looks ugly...

Comment: @TLama I am not stealing or i'm going to upload it on the internet. Its only for my porsonal use where i included the updates into the setup so i should not download them again.

Comment: @TLama If i had the intention of Piracy then i would have modified the image and posted.

Comment: I don't mind. Don't worry! ;-)

Comment: @TLama Okay. Can you slove this? I am a noob in coding.

Comment: I don't know what to solve. What's the problem with the code that @Martin posted ?

Comment: @TLama Can you please update Martin's Code with the codes that you have put up. I asked you this because i am a noob in coding mate.

Answer (score 2):

The ISSI does not handle a `RunList` (list of checkboxes on "finish" page) at all.

I cannot test it, but this should do:

```pascal
#define ISSI_InitializeWizard

[Code]
procedure ISSI_InitializeWizard;
begin
  { Not sure about the value. You have to experiment here. }
  WizardForm.RunList.Left := ???;
end;
```

Comment: I am getting a error saying "[ISPP] Undeclared Identifier "InitializeWizard".

Comment: Yep. `RunList` remains untouched in the whole ISSI project. This is [`what happens inside`](http://pastebin.com/azJ7VGBA) with the final page. Don't know if that won't be soon, but you can try to set the position e.g. to `WizardForm.RunList.Left := WizardForm.FinishedLabel.Left` (optionally also the width).

Comment: @TLama It's too soon, as `ISSI_InitializeWizard` is called before `InitializeWizard_WizardBitmapImage`.

Comment: You are right (I was just lazy to check that :) Well, then you can set it to `ISSI_WizardBitmap2_X + 18` because that is hardcoded in the script (when `ISSI_WizardBitmapImage` is defined).

Comment: @MartinPrikryl: I have tried puting the values but doesn't show the changes.

Comment: Try WizardForm.RunList.Left :=  WizardForm.RunList.Left + 20;

Answer (score 1):

**Here is the Solution given in another forum:**

```
[ISSI]
;SplashScreen
; Name of the bitmap image:
#define ISSI_SplashScreen "C:\Users\Archangel_7\Downloads\Newfolder\AA_7.bmp "
; Time in seconds:
#define ISSI_SplashScreen_T 1
; Image Width:
#define ISSI_SplashScreen_X 488
; Image Heigth:
#define ISSI_SplashScreen_Y 199
; Include ISSI (required)
#define ISSI_IncludePath "C:\ISSI"
#include ISSI_IncludePath+"\_issi.isi"
;WizardSmallBitmapImage [Default = [55x55]
#define ISSI_WizardSmallBitmapImage"C:\Users\Archangel_7\D ownloads\ensemble.bmp"
#define ISSI_WizardSmallBitmapImage_x 70
;WizardBitmapImage [Front & Back] [Default = 164x314]
#define ISSI_WizardBitmapImage"C:\Users\Archangel_7\Downlo ads\AOE.bmp"
#define ISSI_WizardBitmapImage_x 180
;define ISSI_WizardBitmapImage_Align
#define ISSI_WizardBitmapImage2 "C:\Users\Archangel_7\Downloads\AOE.bmp"
#define ISSI_WizardBitmapImage2_x 180
;define ISSI_WizardBitmapImage2_Align
;[Background Image]
;define ISSI_Image "C:\Users\Archangel_7\Downloads\AA7.bmp"

[Setup]
.....

[Languages]
.....

[Tasks]
....

[Files]
Source: C:\Users\Archangel_7\Desktop\Age of Empires\Redistributable\Directx\Dplay50a.exe; DestDir: {app}\Redistributable\Directx
Source: C:\Users\Archangel_7\Desktop\Age of Empires\Redistributable\Directx\Dxsetup.exe; DestDir: {app}\Redistributable\Directx

[Icons]
....

[Registry]
....

[Dirs]
....

[Run]
Filename: {app}\Redistributable\Directx\Dxsetup.exe; Description: Direct X; Flags: postinstall
Filename: {app}\Redistributable\Directx\Dplay50a.exe; Description: Direct Play v5.0a; Flags: postinstall

#define ISSI_UseMyCurPageChanged
[Code]
procedure ISSI_CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
if CurPageID = wpFinished then
begin
WizardForm.RunList.Left:=198
end;
end;
#define ISSI_IncludePath "C:\ISSI"
#include ISSI_IncludePath+"\_issi.isi"
```